# Bash: Kill Vim when "Vim: Warning: Output not to a terminal"

Tags: bash, vim

Every once in awhile I make a mistake at the command line, and use vim in a subshell.

This of course locks up that terminal window, and outputs a bunch of errors, with the main error being

```
Vim: Warning: Output not to a terminal
```

**Is there a way for me to configure vim so it automatically dies when this happens, and doesn't hang my terminal?**

I know I could probably figure out the process id of this vim instance, and kill it, but I would like a better solution if possible, as I tend to run lots of different vim instances in different tmux panes/windows. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. I don't mean to object overmuch, but asking how to make something *automatic* and then accepting a purely *manual* answer seems a bit... surprising.

Comment: good point - i forgot about that, and just thought the "no code" solution was probably easier for most people - but you're right for sure, and I'm switching back to your answer ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can prevent it from starting in the first place easily enough. Consider putting the following function definition in your `.bashrc`:

```
vim() {
  [ -t 1 ] || { echo "Not starting vim without stdout to TTY!" >&2; return 1; }
  command vim "$@"
}
```

The `command` builtin prevents recursing, by ensuring that it invokes an external command (rather than just calling the function again).

Similarly, you could create a script `$HOME/bin/vim`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  exec /usr/bin/vim "$@"
else
  echo "Not starting vim without stdout to TTY!" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

...put `$HOME/bin` first in your `PATH`, and let that shim do the work without relying on a shell function.

Comment: How does it work? Which program would be calling the `vim` function?

Comment: @user2023370, "which program"? The user's interactive shell. (If that shell isn't bash, one would want to put it in a different file as appropriate).

Comment: @user2023370 The ***program*** who made the bug... When the bug is located between the keyboard and the chair. ;-)

Answer (score 48):

Not aware of any configuration option that does this, but when this happens if you type `:q<Enter>`, it will quit vim.

Also, while Ctrl-C will not work, Ctrl-Z will put vim in the background and then you can kill it with `kill %1`.

Comment: I like the script approach, but appreciate this answer as well, as I think this would work on other systems - though I feel I've tried this before in some lock up scenarios and it didn't help. I did just try it by doing something like so: `vim $(vim /tmp/it.json)` which happens to me sometimes when I recall the last command to edit a file and don't do an expansion first.

Comment: @BradParks, for that case `vim $(vim x)` you can exit by typing `:q<Enter>` twice.

Comment: In my case it was `<ESC>` and then force quite with `:q<Enter>`

Answer (score 32):

Or the vim short cut
 `ZQ`
Capital letters. You can use it in normal mode :-)

Comment: +1 Both `Ctrl-Z` and `Ctrl-C` didn't work for me, it returned me a message `job can't be suspended` without being able to do anything. This `ZQ` worked, thanks!

Comment: ZQ saved the day for me

Answer (score 12):

You can just type this and hit enter, even though it is not showing up in the stdout it is still being input:

1. type the below
   :q!
2. Execute keyboard key
   Return/Enter

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above doesn't work then try using the following:
press `esc` once and then use either

```
:qa
```

or

```
SHIFT ZZ
```